IIS isn't able to access the work (companydomain.com) files. It works when I change the ownership of file to make it personal
We created a couple of websites in IIS (latest), one for API and one for web application.


Now when I am trying to access the site, I am facing this weird problem from last couple of months. Everything used to work well before that.

When I check the web.config file, I see that file ownership is of work account-

Now, changing the file ownership to Personal works but 95%+ config/json/js/css files in my website is having the same problem.
What I tried is-

Tried taking ownership of all files with bash command, but it didn't work-


takeown /f "C:\Workspace\mainwebapp" /r /d Y


Tried taking ownership of all files with PowerShell, but it didn't work-


Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Workspace\mainwebapp" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
Takeown /f $_.FullName
}


Tried connecting as specific user-


The last approach solves the problem (somewhat) but it's having its own issues, and I think it is not a proper solution.
As I mentioned earlier, everything used to work properly as it is, and it only stopped working from a last couple of months. Can someone please point me in right direction? I wanted to understand what happened here and what might be causing this problem all of the sudden.

OneDrive has a very complex permission system, but IIS expects the simplest. So, please don’t map any IIS site/application to a OneDrive folder. There were quite a lot of similar issues reported over the years.

What user is the app pool running as?

Hi @mjwills, the default, ApplicationPoolIdentity is the identity of the app pool user.
